# How can I autoload my classes in the classes folder with composer?

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I've tried to add the following to my composer.json file.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "classes/"
    }
}
```

Upon doing this I would get errors when trying to reference my classes. I do not want them to have a namespace. I would like to be able to access my classes as if I had:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

`spl_autoload_register` is working on all my files, I cannot seem to get composer to work due to being new to it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Read [Autoloading Primer](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/388/autoloading-primer#t=20160906213656644711), [Composer Basics](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), [Composer Autoload Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload), and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. Is path correct? Did you `composer dumpautoload` and `require_once "path/to/vendor/autoload.php";` ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Thank you very much. Seems like the issue was that I wasn't `running dumpautoload`. Could you explain to me what this function does?

Comment: I hardly can explain it better than in the docs https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using what @AlexBlex said. The main issue was that I was not running `composer dumpautoload` after changing my `composer.json` file.